# Shell file size in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

How can I get the size of a file into a variable?

```
ls -l | grep testing.txt | cut -f6 -d' '
```

gave the size, but how can I store it in a shell variable?

Comment: yes it's bash shell and thank you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check size of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920333/how-to-check-size-of-a-file)

Comment: Looks like other question was asked in 2011

Comment: Yes, but has better answers.

Comment: Better answer, yes. But doesn't mean this question is duplicate of another question which was created a year later!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
filesize=$(stat -c '%s' testing.txt)
```

Comment: `stat -f '%z'` on MacOS X.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way with `ls` (check the man page for the meaning of *-s*)

```
var=$(ls -s1 testing.txt | awk '{print $1}')
```

Or you can use `stat` with `-c '%s'`.

Or you can use [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) (GNU):

```
var=$(find testing.txt -printf "%s")
```

Comment: the find solution works on MINGW and git bash on Windows.  None of the other answers work on MINGW.

Comment: If you wanted a version that worked on *every* POSIX system, `wc -c` would be better than either relying on `ls` behavior *or* on having GNU `find` or `stat` available.

Comment: Note that wc -c is more accurate for pseudo files like /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 2):

```
size() {
  file="$1"
  if [ -b "$file" ]; then
    /sbin/blockdev --getsize64 "$file"
  else
    wc -c < "$file"  # Handles pseudo files like /proc/cpuinfo
    # stat --format %s "$file"
    # find "$file" -printf '%s\n'
    # du -b "$file" | cut -f1
  fi
}

fs=$(size testing.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
size=`ls -l | grep testing.txt | cut -f6 -d' '`
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the size will be in field 6 when space-delimited.

Comment: This is also inefficient because piping `ls` into `grep` lists *all* files in the directory and sorts their names (which can take a substantial amount of time in a directory with thousands of files), and additionally error-prone because `grep testing.txt` also returns files with names like `not_testingatxt_file` (as `.` in a regex means match-any-character).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size in bytes with the command `wc`, which is fairly common on Linux systems since it's part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html):

```
wc -c < file
```

In a Bash script you can read it into a variable like this:

```
FILESIZE=$(wc -c < file)
```

From [`man wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc):

```
-c, --bytes
       print the byte counts
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    a=\`stat -c '%s' testing.txt\`;
    echo $a
```