# Explain the working of the command ls -l | grep testing.txt | cut -f6 -d' '

Tags: linux, bash, shell

These two commands can save the size of a file into a variable, as I am new to linux I cant understand there working. Kindly explain how they works.

```
    ls -l | grep testing.txt | cut -f6 -d' '

    filesize=$(stat -c '%s' testing.txt)
```

These commands are taken from: [linux shell file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236113/linux-shell-file-size)

Comment: The first command does *not* save the size of a file to a variable.

Comment: That's a really awful way to collect file size on Linux -- it's extremely open to bugs. Don't do it that way.

Comment: ...in fact, why don't you ask for the *right* way to do it, instead of asking how a wrong way works?

Comment: Thanks @lurker for your reply, I know that first command didn't save it to the variable, but I want to know that what is grep or cut -f6 -d ' ' is doing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure, I can ask it, will you answer that question?

Comment: `man cut` and `man grep` are good ways to find out.

Comment: Have you checked the man page for `grep` and for `cut`? `grep` only allows text lines in its in put pass through to the output that match the given expression (in this case, that match `testing.txt`). And `cut` selects certain fields from the text. In this case, field number 6 with a delimiter of space.

Comment: Pay attention to Charles' comment. listing a directory and limiting file selection with `grep` and piping to `cut` is a train wreck. If there are multiple files, e.g. (`limit-testing.txt, time-testing.txt, ...`) you can end up with unwanted results.

Comment: It doesn't work at all because of variable length fields. The size field varies in size , and when it does you get junk.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck trimming the output of `ls` using `sed`, but the stat command is a much better way to go.

Comment: @EricHughes, ...I'd actually suggest `awk`, given its default behavior of treating runs of separators as a single column separation, if for some reason one had no choice but to parse `ls` (being, for instance, on a system with no GNU `stat` and no `perl`, and a version of `wc -c` that doesn't optimize by using `stat` data).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good point!  I too often just reach for `sed` and mash regexes together until something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stat --format=%s testing.txt
```

or

```
stat -c '%s' testing.txt
```

moreover you can man the stat page to understand what %s or %A do.

Comment: What does this add when compared to pre-existing answers? It offers an alternative (already given in other answers), but doesn't answer the literal question (explaining how the original command worked) at all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Really, don't.

```
stat --format=%s testing.txt
```

...relies on having GNU stat, but is much more efficient and reliable (on any system where GNU stat is available).

```
filesize=$(stat --format=%s testing.txt)
```

...does the same thing, but saves the result into a variable named `filesize` (just as you'd need to do with the `ls` result to save its result for use anywhere else).

---

On a system without GNU stat, you might also consider:

```
filesize=$(wc -c <testing.txt)
```

...which will, if written by a sane person, seek to the end of the file and check its position, rather than reading all contents (a much more expensive test).

---

```
ls -l | grep testing.txt | cut -f6 -d' '
```

1. lists *all* files (rather than looking only at the one file you care about), thus being much slower on large directories (with directories with tens of thousands of files or more, this could take minutes).
2. filters only for names that contain `testing.txt` (where the `.` can be any character -- it would find `testingatxt` as well, or `sometesting8txtbye.jpg`).
3. dividing the results into columns by spaces, takes the 6th column from **each** line found.

Note that step `3` is particularly error-prone, because the specification for `ls` doesn't make any promises about how many spaces will exist between each column in `ls -l`, so there's no guarantee that this will work the way you expect.

See also [Why You Shouldn't Parse the Output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: The %s is for size is it possible to save the permissions of a file in a variable like string

Comment: `man stat` will give you a list of available format strings. `%a` and `%A` will, as that documentation notes, give you access writes in either a numeric (octal) value or a human-readable one, as preferred.

Comment: One more thing, you said that filesize=$(stat --format=%s testing.txt) this command is a better option what if I want to put a variable instead of testing.txt?

Comment: @AliSajid, then use `"$varname"` in place of `testing.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the second command saves anything into anything.

The first command takes the output of `ls -l`, pipes it to `grep` which looks for lines matching `testing.txt`, then pipes those lines to `cut`, which removes portions of the lines.  In this case, it selects only the 6th field `-f6`, and uses spaces as field delimiters `-d' '`

The second command performs the `stat` operation on the file in question, then saves the result to a variable.